# Toast on an clickable ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, toast

Could someone help on setting a toast message up for a clickable ImageView(which is linked to a URL)?

This is what I've got so far, but I'm not sure why it is giving me an error on 'maketext'. 
Thankyou in advance if anyone could point me in the right direction!

```
    public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView blipImg;
    ImageView breakImg;
    ImageView dailyMotionImg;
    ImageView funnyOrDieImg;
    ImageView metaCafeImg;
    ImageView netFlixImg;
    ImageView socialCamImg;
    ImageView tedImg;
    ImageView vevoImg;
    ImageView viddyImg;
    ImageView vimeoImg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.video1);
       blipImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.videoBlip);
       blipImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Blip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            }
       });

       breakImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.videoBreak);
       breakImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://break.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Break",                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            }
    });
            }
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are putting your ImageView into your Toast and that can't work.

change

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(blipImg, "Blip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
```

to

```
 Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Blip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thanks guys. that's awesome. was trying to figure out what 'context' it meant, but I understand it now.

Comment: btw, if I had multiple clickable ImageViews(such as the one in the original question), would the same thing work if I followed each iteration of the code for the ImageView with a toast, or would I have to do something else?

Comment: clickable ImageViews = ImageButtons. Also i didn't really understand your last question :/

Comment: If I had 2 ImageButtons, both set up like the code above, it would seem the toast only works for the first ImageButton. Is there something I have to do differently with the toast for the second ImageButton?

Comment: thats hard to guess not seeing your other imagebuttons' implementation. But basically you can put Toasts almost everywhere. It is like a Log-message or System.out.println();

Comment: @bofredo not quite, almost anywhere that runs on the `UI Thread`. Logs don't have to be on the `UI Thread` but `Toast` messages do

Comment: I have ammended to the code above, but as it runs, the toast message will only show up for the first ImageButton. Is it something wrong with the code do you think? Thanks for this guys.

Comment: the code is correct. now i am curious why this isn't working for you :)

Comment: @bofredo just a silly issue, not updating my .apk file properly :s sorry about that!! thanks again lads.

Comment: @user2788363 glad i could help ya. g'day sir :)

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29), this method takes a Context as the first parameter, not the View on which the user clicks, try this instead (using your Activity as Context) :

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Blip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are passsing blipImg instead of context

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this , "Blip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

OR

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this.getApplicationContext() , "Blip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `makeText`, the first parameter should be the context of the `Toast` (change it to `VideoActivity.this`).

Answer (score 0):

Toast.makeText() takes different parameters, you should pass your activity context instead of the ImageView. Also Toast is static so call it like this:

```
Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Blip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said so far, you are using the wrong `param` in `makeText()`. You can use `ActivityName.this` and it will work but a better practice would be to use the `Context` of the `View` being clicked, which in this case will give you the same `Context` as `ActivityName.this` but it is better practice.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Blip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

For instacne, if you want to move or reuse this code somewhere else then you don't need to change `ActivityName`